# How to configure Wayfinder (ModX Revo) to geht this output

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I can't figure out how I have to configure Wayfinder (or pdoMenue) to get this output:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">

                    <p>Home</p>
                </a>
            </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="articles.html">

                    <p>Articles</p>
                </a>
            </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">

                    <p>About</p>
                </a>
            </li>


        </ul>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Edit: I have a dropdown too:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a href="index.html#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">
<i class="now-ui-icons files_paper" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p>Sections</p>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria- labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="sections.html#headers">
  <i class="now-ui-icons shopping_box"></i>
  Headers
 </a>
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="sections.html#features">
  <i class="now-ui-icons ui-2_settings-90"></i>
  Features
 </a>

 </div>
 </li>
```

It is the free Template Now UI-Kit, and based on bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[pdoMenu?
    &parents=`0`
    &level=`1`
    &tplOuter=`@INLINE <ul[[+classes]]>[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
    &tpl=`@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><a class="nav-link" href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]><p>[[+menutitle]]</p></a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
    &outerClass=`navbar-nav ml-auto`
    &rowClass=`nav-link`
]]
```

Something like this in pdoMenu. Untested, you may have to play around with how the classes get assigned. If you need first and last classes, or a you-are-here class, those are available too and well-documented. https://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdomenu

Comment: Thanks you. Thats help me a lot. There is a dropdown menu. I edit the question with that code. Do you habe an Idea about that?

Comment: You'll need to add the parent template. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried it with tplInner...and tplInnerRow...but that does not work. The whole thing confused me to the fullest.

Comment: As I mentioned, you'll also need the parent template and classes. Post your code so we can help debug it.